# Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.10.12

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install express using command "npm install express", however I keep getting the following error message

```
Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.10.12
Required: node@0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:57:23
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:77:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

It seems npm doesn't work with node v0.10.*

Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: What's the output of `npm -v` ?  It's possible you are using an outdated version of npm that doesn't support the newest node.

Comment: Reinstall your Node.js which will install a compatible and latest version of npm.

Comment: npm -v gives me a very long error message that can't be posted here

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running an older version of `npm` by mistake. Both `node` and `npm` should come together in the node distribution and you should use them in that matched pair and all will be well. Check your `PATH` environment variable, `which npm`, `which node`, etc and you should be able to sort it out.

Comment: I will uninstall everything and re-install and see if that will fix it